# Setting UIView to Start From Upper-Left Corner (0,0)

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer, viewcontroller, uipangesturerecognizer

I adapted a UIPanGestureRecognizer to use pull-down to dismiss view. I made it like this, so now the view can be dragged the in y-axis and if change in y is greater than 100, it dismisses the view.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let myPanGestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "myPanAction:")
    self.player.view.addGestureRecognizer(myPanGestureRecognizer)
}

func myPanAction(recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        if let myView = recognizer.view {
            myView.center = CGPoint(x: myView.center.x, y: myView.center.y + translation.y)
        }
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
            let velocity = recognizer.velocityInView(self.view)

            if velocity.y > 100 {
                dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
            } else {
                // Reposition Back                   
            }
        }
}
```

However, I want to position the view back to its original place but, I couldn't figure out how..

Also, is my approach a good way of doing it or is it a very primitive approach?

Comment: Have you tried to set the center of your view to the original position? You can have a reference to the original center on your view controller if needed.

Comment: I am relatively new to Swift, so I didn't get what to do actually :/ What I am trying to achieve is placing the view to start  (x, y) from (0,0) - upper-left corner

Comment: Not sure if it will work but give it a try: 
`let frame = myView.frame`
`frame.origin = CGPointMake(0, 0)`
`myView.frame = frame`

Comment: I got confused understanding your approach :/ CGPointMake seems I need to give random number, but feels like it won't compile for each screen.. All I want is basically make the top left corner of uiview to place itself (0,0)

Comment: That's what I'm suggesting, I'll try to put on an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to add on the `// Reposition Back` comment the following code:

```
let frame = myView.frame // Get the current view frame
frame.origin = CGPointZero // Change the frame origin to x:0 y:0
myView.frame = frame // Change the myView frame to frame
```

Comment: Works like charm!! Thanks a lot! I added a `animateWithDuration` to make it seem more natural.. Just for learning, is there a way of use animateWithDuration while dismissViewController?

Comment: Good to know, not sure if I followed your other question though. By the way, although manipulating frames works I'd suggest checking **autolayout** for view size and position manipulation. Have you heard about it? If not, I'd suggest checking this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115440/auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-9-part-1-getting-started-2) to get yourself familiar with the concept.

Comment: Yes, I know about autolayout, but for this view only, I didn't create a VC on Storyboard. Thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Cool, because with autolayout you could manipulate the vertical constraint between `myView` and it's superview.

Comment: Go for it mate! Any issue we are here to help :)